# If a Juju HA Cluster charm fails to deploy, will removing the HA cluster charm service mess up the service that was behind it?

Tags: server, juju, openstack

I deployed the Havana version of Openstack Keystone, and an the also deployed the HA Cluster charm for it and added a relation. It failed to deploy (I assume because I failed to generate a key instead of using the default specified).

If I just remove the keystone-hacluster service, will it leave the Keystone service in a questionable state or will it clean up? (How does it do this if it is on the same machine?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be great to understand why your deployment of HA Cluster with Keystone failed; for most of the OpenStack API services (Cinder, Glance, Nova Cloud Controller and Keystone), a VIP (Virtual IP) is required to complete clustering - for example:

```
juju set keystone vip=192.168.22.1
```

The relation between HA Cluster and Keystone will fail to establish with a hook error if this is not supplied.  If you did not provide this prior to relating HA Cluster with Keystone, you can set it as described above and resolve/retry the relation that failed:

```
juju resolved --retry keystone/0
```

Hopefully this will resolve the error and result in a functioning, clustered Keystone.

As your cluster never formed, your should also be able to remove the relation between HA Cluster and Keystone; however your will have to manually resolve any failed relations before Juju will let you do this:

```
juju resolved keystone/0
juju remove-relation keystone hacluster
```

Note that if you had managed to form a cluster removing the relation will not de-cluster the service; it locks in the configuration.